# Split a string at the occurance of another string in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have an XML file containing some data in it. One tag among them is the version tag.

I need to open the file, increment the version by 1 and save it. The should be automated using PowerShell-3.

I used -match to get the line having the version tag. The line looks like this:

```
<file version="18" date="12/24/2014" time="14:09" softwareversion="2.19.3">
```

Approach followed:

Take the above string into a variable and use split on it as show.

```
$line = '<file version="18" date="12/24/2014" time="14:09" softwareversion="2.19.3">'
$line.split('file version="')
```

so that I can get the split lines , take the third one, update the version present in it, and add them up together, and write to the file.

Expected output of the split is:

```
<
file version="
18" date="12/24/2014" time="14:09" softwareversion="2.19.3">
```

But I was getting sth like below.

```
<













18    

dat    


11/15/2014

t
m    


12:03
PM




twa










2.19.3
>
```

How do I substring the line at 'file version="' or how do I update the version number in a much simpler way (if possible) ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.Split() splits on each character in the character string.  So you were getting a split on 'f', 'i', 'l', etc

The Powershell -split operator appears to do what you want.

```
PS D:\> $line -split 'file version="'
<
18" date="12/24/2014" time="14:09" softwareversion="2.19.3">
```

Or, if you want the delimiter to be included in the results...

```
PS D:\> $line -split '(file version=")'
<
file version="
18" date="12/24/2014" time="14:09" softwareversion="2.19.3">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was trying to do :)

Answer (score 4):

Or you can work it as a XML file like ths.

```
$XML_CONTENT = [xml]'<file version="18" date="12/24/2014" time="14:09" softwareversion="2.19.3"></file>'
$VERSION_VALUE = [int]$XML_CONTENT.GetElementsByTagName("file").GetAttribute("version")
$XML_CONTENT.GetElementsByTagName("file").SetAttribute("version",($VERSION_VALUE + 1))
$XML_CONTENT.save("OUTPUTFILE.xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just trying to up date the `softwareversion="2.19.3"` number in the string you could just replace it like this:

```
$nextVersion = "2.19.4"
$line = '<file version="18" date="12/24/2014" time="14:09" softwareversion="2.19.3">'
$line = $line -replace 'softwareversion=".*"',('softwareversion="'+$nextVersion+'"')
```

And then just write `$line` to the file.

Comment: The version number is unknown, I should be getting the version no dynamically and incrementing it by 1. Thanks for the reply though :)